# problems with tr1/regex. Prints opposite result

Tags: c++, regex, tr1

Any idea why the following code prints "***no match***"? Something related with the compiler or the version of the library? I compiled with g++ a.cpp.

```
#include <tr1/regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const std::tr1::regex pattern("(\\w+day)");

   std::string weekend = "Saturday and Sunday";

   std::tr1::smatch result;

   bool match = std::tr1::regex_search(weekend, result, pattern);

   if(match)
   {
      for(size_t i = 1; i < result.size(); ++i)
      {
         std::cout << result[i] << std::endl;
      }
   }else
    std::cout << "no match" << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a short complete testcase.

Comment: the code is so obvious that I am suspecting incomplete support of the compiler (at least at my version) towards the standard. How can I verify this?

Comment: Just for reference - MSVC 2010 SP1 (16.00.40219.01) compiles and finds the match properly. You did not specify the version of GCC you are using.

Comment: In g++ 4.6.1, and g++ 4.3.4, this statement asserts: `assert( std::tr1::regex_search("a", std::tr1::regex("a")) );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely an issue with your compiler. I would recommend (since you're on Linux and that makes it particularly easy) to simply swap out `<tr1/regex>` for `<boost/regex.hpp>`. The namespace also becomes `boost::` instead of `std::tr1::` but all other syntax is exactly the same and it may solve all your problems.

If you can't use boost, that's a whole different story; but as of the past year or so, most people/employers/companies have been much more boost-friendly.

Also note that your test case is flawed. You have a loop, but it'll only ever print a single value. `regex_search` returns a value at a time, you need to keep calling it with the new search start index to get all results. If you said the output of the program was nothing (vs "no match"), then I would say the bug was in your code. But the code *as it is currently written* should return `"Saturday"` or `""`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the (). In some regexp implementations you must use `\(` for grouping. And anyways you probably don't need it.

The most basic regexp for this would be:

```
"[a-zA-Z]+day"
```

And you would get the results by `result[0]`

Comment: still "no match". Looks a compiler prob